# How to resolve linker (ld) error for "odbc" library not found (-lodbc)?

Tags: macos, ld, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to track down a problem while installing Pyodbc (`pip install pyodbc`) on Mac OS X 10.12.6 (Sierra) that results in the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lodbc
```

The linker (`ld`) is looking for the library "odbc" and not finding it. I'm assuming that the linker can handle a dynamic library but perhaps it is looking for a static library file (i.e. `libodbc.a`).

Now I had installed **unixODBC** like so:

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl -O ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.4.tar.gz
tar xzvf unixODBC*.tar.gz
cd unixODBC*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

My question is unfortunately a bit broad because I'm not very knowledgeable about this subject. These might lead me in the right direction: Where is `ld` looking for libraries? What library (file) names would it be looking for? I see `libodbc.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`; shouldn't that be the library that is linked? And ... How can I debug this further?

P.S. -- I'm trying to do this without using Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

`ld` is looking in `/usr/lib/` for `libodbc.dylib` but that directory cannot be modified due to SIP (System Integrity Protection) implemented in El Capitan and beyond.

Since the library file is actually at `/usr/local/lib/`, I fixed the issue by adding `-L/usr/local/lib` to the `ld` parameters.

For Python packages, added `['library_dirs'] = '/usr/local/lib'` to your compiler settings. I've done this for a local clone of Pyodbc and it worked!